# Bluetooth Headphones Require Pairing Twice to Work

Tags: xubuntu, bluetooth, headphones

I notice that when I need to connect my Bluetooth headphones to my Xubuntu 20.04 laptop, I have to pair them twice in the Bluetooth Devices GUI. Similarly, if I want to connect via the command line, I need to run the connection command, wait a few seconds, and then run the connection command again. I've written a bash script to connect my headphones, and this is what it needs to do for the pairing to be successful:

```
echo -e "connect <MAC address of headphones>\n" | bluetoothctl
sleep 10
echo -e "connect <MAC address of headphones>\n" | bluetoothctl
```

I don't understand why I have to pair my headphones twice for them to work. I would appreciate any insights the community might have.

Comment: Unfortunately that happens with certain peripherals. I haven't found a solutions either.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you why but i have just noticed that this only occures when the headphones are paired. If you start from scratch and directly connect, there appears to be only one device, but when paired, two devices appear. My headphones work fine without pairing. But i would be also interested to understand this behaviour a little better.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1240860)